# DNS SPF TXT Records - is this legal?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, txt-record

**foo.org  1  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.bar.com ~all"**

**foo.org  1  IN  TXT  "v-spf1 ip4:99.99.99.99 include:_spf.google.com ~all"**

or do they need to be combined into one record because of the two references to google?

Comment: [MxToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx) has a range of tools to help diagnose email, dns, and network issues - including an SPF validator. You just enter your domain (`foo.org`), and it will check your DNS records.

Answer (score 9):

According to [RFC 7208 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.2):

> 3.2.  Multiple DNS Records
>
> A domain name MUST NOT have multiple records that would cause an    authorization check to select more than
> one record.  See Section 4.5    for the selection rules.

And [section 4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.5) says:

> If the resultant record set includes more than one record,
> check_host() produces the "permerror" result.

In practical terms, if there is more than one record, this is an error and all records would then be ignored by the querying entity, *if it is RFC-compliant* - something that is never guaranteed. Implementation and the level of adherence to standards is variable from one piece of software to another. Bottom line, deviating from the RFCs and established standards is a risky road. Try to stick to them as much as possible.